# Angular Scope within Directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Given this fairly simple angular wrapper for a JQuery UI button:

```
angular.module('Sample.controllers', [])
  .controller('mainController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.jump =  function () {alert("jump");};
   }])
  .directive('jquiwButton', function() {
    return {
      scope: {},
      restrict: 'A',
      replace:true,
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var options = {};
        if (angular.isDefined(attrs["jquiDisabled"])) {
          options.disabled = attrs["jquiDisabled"];
        }

        if (angular.isDefined(attrs["jquiIconPrimary"])) {
          if (!angular.isDefined(options.icons.primary)) {
            options.icons ={};
          }
          options.icons.primary = attrs["jquiIconPrimary"];
        }

        if (angular.isDefined(attrs["jquiIconSecondary"])) {
          if (!angular.isDefined(options.icons.secondary)) {
            options.icons ={};
          }
          options.icons.secondary = attrs["jquiIconSecondary"];
        }

        if (angular.isDefined(attrs["jquiLabel"])) {
          options.label = attrs["jquiLabel"];
        }

        if (angular.isDefined(attrs["jquiText"])) {
          options.text = attrs["jquiText"];
        }

        element.button(options);
      }
    };
  });
  angular.module('Sample', ['Sample.controllers']);
```

And the markup.

```
<body ng-controller="mainController"> 
  <button jquiw-button jqui-label="Hello" ng-click="jump()">Hello</button>
</body>
```

and it works fine until I add a scope at which point I lose the ability to use the standard angular bindings to the outer scope. In my case the markup `ng-click='jump()' now won't work because it can't find the method jump which is defined in the outer context and not in the isolate scope.  Now I know that I can specifically bind ng-click back to the outer scope but I want to avoid doing that since it requires knowledge of all the possible directives I might need to bind.

So my question is:  How do I let other directives work in the outer scope while still having an isolate scope?

plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/eRoOeq?p=preview

Remove line 8:  `scope: {},` and it ng-click calls the correct function.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do that.... still have a look at how ng-repeat is implemented....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-click="$parent.jump()"`.

Comment: That would work but it seems inellegant.  Is there a better way to say something like "for all things I don't define in my scope, let it be in the outer scope"?

Comment: It works sza.  It seems like using scope is not a very good idea unless you are intentionally isolating.  I guess it it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference a function in the parent scope from inside the isolate scope by using the `&` binding. This is the proper way to call a function from an isolate scope inside a directive [according to the directive documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

I created a [working CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tyCFn) to demonstrate it working flawlessly.

Here's the relevant parts:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.jump = function() {
    alert('jump called');
  };
});

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      call: '&'
    },
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.call();
    }
  };
});
```

and in the template:

```
<section ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <my-directive call="jump()"></my-directive>
</section>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: But wont this require advanced knowledge and mapping of those external directives?  In other words, I may not know that the user is going to bind ng-blur or ng-change and so this method would require I have fore-knowledge of all possible bindings and then manually bind them.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you are worrying about something that should never happen. If you are creating a brand new directive, then you are dictating the usage. If another developer places an `ng-click` or `ng-blur` on your element without consulting your directive documentation, then they are taking their own chances. Potential users of your new directive should be aware that your directive uses specific attributes.

Comment: I suppose that is true but it still requires that I write binding code for each directive even though I not doing anything other than what the directive would normally do - this could well be a design feature and the answer is "Don't use your own scope unless you want to isolate your directive from exactly this sort of thing."  which seems to be the case.  It seems isolate scope really is to isolate.

Comment: This is actually a great question. I have wondered the same thing regarding passing through native `ng-*` directives on our custom directives without explicitly binding them in the isolate scope. What I am finding is that even among native angular directives they don't always place nice together. That leads me to believe that the prescribed usage be strictly adhered to. That further leads me to believe that dictating usage of our own custom directives is acceptable.